# $[0,1]$ cannot be the union of two disjoint images of continuous maps

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and, let $f,g:X\to X$ be continuous such that $f(X)\cap g(X)=\emptyset$  and $f(X)\cup g(X)=X$.Then $X$ cannot be equal to

1. $[0,1]$
2. $(0,1)$
3. $[0,1)$
4. $\mathbb{R}$

I think the answer is 1 because it is a closed set of $\mathbb{R}$.Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't this work for any subset $X \subset \mathbb R$ if $f(x) = g(x) = x$?

Comment: @amcerbu thanks, edited the question

Comment: Okay, cool. Hint: the image of $[0,1]$ under a continuous function is closed and bounded. Can you write $[0,1]$ as a disjoint union of two closed, bounded sets? (And if you believe the answer is $X=[0,1]$, can you come up with functions $f,g$ that work for the other three?)

Comment: @amcerbu thanks, does $f=\frac{x}{2}$ & $g=\frac{x+1}{2}$ work for $(0,1)$?

Comment: Not quite... neither of your functions ever hits $1/2$. Can you modify one of them to make it work?

Comment: @amcerbu unable to modify the function. Any hints?

Comment: What if $f$ is defined piecewise: $f(x) = x$ for $x \in (0,1/2)$ and $f(x) = 1/2$ for $x \in [1/2,1)$?

Comment: @amcerbu thanks, wrote the answer.

Comment: If this were a test Q with exactly one correct answer, you could immediately eliminate 2. and 4. because $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R,$  so if $X$ can't be one of these, then it can't be the other. But then there would be at least 2 correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.
For $X=[0,1]$, $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ will be line segments, and if $f(X)\cap g(X)=\emptyset$, $f(X)\cup g(X)$ will not be connected.

For the others, for example,

- $f(x)={x\over2}$, $g(x)=2x(x-1)+1$, if $X=(0,1)$
- $f(x)={x\over2}$, $g(x)={x+1\over2}$, if $X=[0,1)$
- $f(x)=x^2$, $g(x)=-e^x$, if $X=\Bbb R$

Note that depending on the definition of a function, $[0,1]$ can also be possible if $f(X)$ or $g(X)$ is empty (that is, if $f$ or $g$ is not well-defined). For example, $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)\in\emptyset$.

Comment: How you have gotten this type of example? Can you suggest me the procedure to find out such example ?

Comment: @S717717 I drew a graph and searched out the form of functions needed, and then determined their formulas.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by amcerbu, since the image of a compact set is compact, which, in this case is closed and bounded, so $[0,1]$ cannot be written as a disjoint union of images of continuous maps defined on the set. However examples of functions can be provided for the other three cases because of those sets being noncompact. Example include:

2)&3)

$$f=\begin{cases} x && x\in(0,1/2) or x\in[0,1/2)\\ 1/2 && x\in[1/2,1)\end{cases}$$ and $$g=\frac{x+1}{2}$$

Similar combinations of piecewise and linear functions work for the last case.